# mfc program using wrong decimal separator/language

Tags: c++, mfc, decimal-point

I have the comma as the decimal separator in my Windows regional settings (Portuguese language), and all the programs I develop use the comma when formatting strings or using `atof`.

However, this particular program that came into my hands insists on using the dot as the decimal separator, regardless of my regional settings.

I'm not calling `setlocale` anywhere in the program or any other language changing function AFAIK. In fact I put these lines of code at the very beginning of the `InitInstance()` function:

```
double var = atof("4,87");
TRACE("%f", fDecimal);
```

This yields `4.000000` in this program and `4,870000` in every other one.

I figure there must be some misplaced setting in the project's properties, but I don't know what it is. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm not calling setlocale anywhere in the program or any other language changing function AFAIK.*

That'd be why.  C and C++ default to the "C" locale.  Try setting the locale to "": `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");`

Comment: You are right. Turns out the other programs referenced a DLL that called `setlocale`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`atof` is relying on the C locale when it comes to determining the expected decimal separator. Thus, as another member mentioned, `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");` will set the C locale to the user locale (regional settings) for number-related functions. See [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx) for more informations on the available flags and the locale names.

For those who don't want to change your C locale, you can use [`atof_l`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc25t012.aspx) instead of the standard `atol` and provide it a locale structure created with [`_create_locale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zx9aht2.aspx) (what a name).

```
double _atof_l(const char *str, _locale_t locale);
```

There are a multitude of alternatives. For example you could use `strtod` (and its Windows [`strtod_l`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab.aspx) counterpart) which is IMHO a better option because it will let you know if something wrong happened.